# Need help in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make so that if user logged in holding the password "tja" in the database send him to one page otherwise another but can't get it to work.

Can anyone please help me with the correct code?

```
//This is the code I have now.

public string mypassword = "tja";

// GET: SmsBuys
public ActionResult Index()
{
      var getuser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
      var getpassword = db.SmsBuys.Where(x => x.code == mypassword);

      if (getpassword == getuser) //This is wrong I know
      {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Buys");
      }
      else
      {
           return View(db.SmsBuys.ToList().Where(x => x.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Password Accessibility**

The password of the current user is really only going to be accessible when they post it to the server.

Thus, you'll likely need to handle it in the actual POST event where your user posts their appropriate log-in credentials to the server to be authenticated into the application.

Let's say you have a very basic form that looks like this for your user to log in :

```
<form action='@Url.Action("SignIn","Account")' method='post'>
     <input name='username' placeholder='Username' />
     <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='Password' />
     <input type='submit' value='Log In' />
</form>
```

When posted, this will look for a SignIn action within your Account Controller that looks like the following, which is where you would handle this logic :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(string username, string password)
{
      // Compare your password
      if(password == yourSpecialPassword)
      {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Buys");
      }

      // If you are still around, authenticate the user here
}
```

The user's password will be passed along in the `password` variable, which you can then use to compare against your database value to determine the best course of action to take.

**Accessing from the Database**

Additionally, if you are reading your password to check against from the database, you'll likely want to use the `FirstOrDefault()` method to pull a single one as opposed to `Where()` which would return a collection of them :

```
var getpassword = db.SmsBuys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == mypassword);
// If a password was found, check against the posted value
if(password == getpassword)
{
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Buys");
}
```

Comment: I have fixed it now, I used a cookie:)

Comment: Are you storing the user's password in a cookie? Doesn't seem practical to persist something sensitive like a password that would only be used to handle redirection.I would highly recommend just handing this within the POST event as I mentioned as it seems to make a bit more sense to me, but your mileage / use-case may vary.

Comment: No no not storing the user's password in a cookie. Just using a cookie so I can write, if(smscookie !=null) go to this site otherwise go to another☺